# Automatic lifting of infix operators to monadic infix operators

Tags: haskell, monads, infix-notation

One of the nice things about Haskell is the ability to use infix notation.

```
1 : 2 : 3 : []    :: Num a => [a]
2 + 4 * 3 + 5     :: Num a => a
```

But this power is suddenly and sadly lost when the operator needs to be lifted.

```
liftM2 (*) (liftM2 (+) m2 m4) (liftM2 (+) m3 m5)
liftM2 (:) m1 (liftM2 (:) m2 (liftM2 (:) m3 mE))
```

It is possible to define similar operators in order to regain this power

```
(.*) = liftM2 (*)
(.+) = liftM2 (+)
(.:) = liftM2 (:)

m1, m2, m3, m4, m5 :: Monad m, Num a => m a
mE = return []     :: Monad m => m [a]
m1 .: m2 .: m3 .: mE    :: Monad m, Num a => m [a]
m2 .+ m4 .* m3 .+ m5    :: Monad m, Num a => m a
```

But it is tedious to need to rename every operator I want to use in a monadic context. Is there a better way? Template Haskell, perhaps?

Comment: If the mX are IO or ST actions you probably do not want to execute them multiple times, because liftM2 (+) m m is then *very* differetn from do n <- m; return n+n

Comment: SHE has idiom brackets which let you write (|f m1 m2 ... mn|) for (pure f <*> m1 <*> m2 <*> ... <*> mn) and (|m1 <> m2|) for (pure (<>) <*> m1 <*> m2). I didn't get around to implementing a fixity-resolving lifter for more complex expressions built from infix operators.

Comment: @Ingo the semantic meaning is to indeed run the effect multiple times. For example, `liftM2 (+) readInt readInt` - in this case I *would* want the `readInt` action performed twice, rather than only once, since it will possibly grab a different int the second time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can define a new infix lift:

```
v <. f = liftM2 f v
f .> v = f v
```

Example use:

```
[3] <.(+).> [4]
```

...but I don't know of any real way that isn't 100% annoying.

Comment: Yeah...I suppose if the same monadic operaters are used over and over, it is less tedious to simply make my own custom operators.

Comment: @Dan, if the same monadic operators are used over and over -- that is, you find yourself lifting the same pure operators into a monad many times, I would venture a guess that your code could stand to be less monadic -- shorter and simpler that way.

Answer (score 10):

You can make all monads instances of `Num`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, FlexibleContexts, UndecidableInstances #-}

import Control.Monad

instance (Monad m, Num n, Show (m n), Eq (m n)) => Num (m n) where
  (+) = liftM2 (+)
  (*) = liftM2 (*)
```

Then you can do f.e.:

```
*Main> [3,4] * [5,6] + [1,2]
[16,17,19,20,21,22,25,26]
```

But this only works for operators that are defined with type classes. With `:` this isn't possible.

Comment: You'll probably need to add dummy `Show` and `Eq` instances for most interesting monads to use this.

Answer (score 2):

There is the style using `ap`:

```
return (:) `ap` Just 1 `ap` Just []
```

or applicative style:

```
(:) <$> Just 1 <*> Just []
```

Comment: This does work, but requires the operators to appear in the prefix position, which is what I would like to avoid.

Comment: You can of course define `x <%> y = y <$> x`. That allows you to write `Just 1 <%> (:) <*> Just []`. I don't know how to do without those pesky parentheses, though.